# MySql Where condition after for after selecting the ranked query

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, rank

Database:

- user - id, name
- message - sender, details, receiver

```
SELECT 
    id, COUNT(sender) AS COUNT, 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(sender) DESC) count_rank  
FROM 
    `message` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `user` ON id = sender  
GROUP BY 
    sender 
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(sender) DESC;
```

```
+----+-------+-----------+
| id | count | count_rank|
+----+-------+-----------+
| 7  | 20    |         1 |
| 4  | 18    |         2 |
| 9  | 18    |         2 |
| 2  |  7    |         4 |
| 5  |  4    |         5 |
+----+-------+-----------+
```

On this output, I only want to get the ID 9 Count and rank

I try

```
SELECT 
    id, COUNT(sender) AS COUNT, 
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(sender) DESC) count_rank  
FROM 
    `message` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `user` ON id = sender 
WHERE 
    `message`.`sender` = 9
 GROUP BY 
     sender 
 ORDER BY 
     COUNT(sender) DESC;
```

But I got the rank as wrong

My result: `Id 9 rank 1`

Expected: `Id 9 rank 2`

Comment: you will not produce same result of `rank()` if you already filtered your result with id=9. all you need is a `subquery`. see Tim Biegeleisen answer, you can also use `select * from ([your original query]) t1, where t1.id = 9`

Answer (score 2):

You need to subquery you current query and then restrict to the `id` you want:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT u.id, m.sender, COUNT(*) AS count,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) count_rank
    FROM message m
    LEFT JOIN user u
        ON u.id = m.sender
    GROUP BY u.id, m.sender
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE id = 9;
```

The reason this is necessary is that if you restrict to `id = 9` in the query which computes the rank, then only records having `id = 9` would be ranked.  But, you want *all* records to be ranked, and then to filter afterwards.